# Sum of method returning value in another method

Tags: java

How can I find the sum of five methods which returns `int`?
Ex.
`int mark = (method1() + method2() + method3() + method4() + method5()+);`
I tried assigning the method to variable but it doesn't work.

Comment: Leave out the last `+`. This should work:
`int mark = method1() + method2() + method3() + method4() + method5();`

Comment: ***but it doesn't work***.... this is not enough information for a good question, we need to see the method1, 2,3,4, and 5 ... and btw, the code you post is not compilant

Comment: I created a mark function that will accept score from English and mathematics test function then sum the score and comment base on the student performance but when I call the mark function instead of it to give the comment then it it give the question that is in mathematics and English function I wish to give the complete code but unable to it said too much to post

Comment: may be you will give me your e-mail to send the code complete

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the `+` sign at the end of your code : `int mark = (method1() + method2() + method3() + method4() + method5()+);`

Change this to :
`int mark = (method1() + method2() + method3() + method4() + method5());`

Now it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove + sign, will give compile time error.

Try this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int mark = (method1() + method2() + method3() + method4() + method5());
    System.out.println("mark=" + mark);
}

public static int method1() {
    return 1;
}

public static int method2() {
    return 2;
}

public static int method3() {
    return 3;
}

public static int method4() {
    return 4;
}

public static int method5() {
    return 5;
}
```